# How to add vertical line to plotly plot

Tags: python, plotly

I am testing plotly express.

I have the latest version: `0.4.1`

I am trying to plot the most basic chart in their tutorial but it's throwing an error:

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="petal_length", y="petal_width")
fig.add_vline(x=2.5, line_width=3, line_dash="dash", line_color="green")
fig.add_hrect(y0=0.9, y1=2.6, line_width=0, fillcolor="red", opacity=0.2)
fig.show()


AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'add_vline'
```

Am I doing something wrong?

All I want to do is to get [`add_vline`](https://plotly.com/python/horizontal-vertical-shapes/) working.

It's the second example on the how-to guide here: https://plotly.com/python/horizontal-vertical-shapes/

Comment: `add_vline` is introduced in plotly 4.12. Please update your package.

Comment: @mosc9575 Would you consider adding that as an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To run the minimal example your package `plotly` has to be up to date as well as your package `plotly.express`.

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="petal_length", y="petal_width")
fig.add_hline(y=0.9)
fig.add_vrect(x0=0.9, x1=2)
fig.show()
```

I quote from the  [documentation](https://plotly.com/python/horizontal-vertical-shapes/) you have shared.

> `add_hline`, `add_vline`, `add_hrect`, and `add_vrect` is introduced in plotly 4.12.

Please bring your package on this or a newer version.

Comment: My `plotly-express` was up to date. Look like I had to update plotly too.

Answer (score 20):

As of plotly version 4.12, which you seem to *not* be running, you can add  [Horizontal and Vertical Lines and Rectangles](https://plotly.com/python/horizontal-vertical-shapes/). So for your case, just use:

```
fig.add_vline()
```

And  there's nothing wrong with your code on my end. This exact snippet:

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="petal_length", y="petal_width")
fig.add_vline(x=2.5, line_width=3, line_dash="dash", line_color="green")
fig.add_hrect(y0=0.9, y1=2.6, line_width=0, fillcolor="red", opacity=0.2)
fig.show()
```

...produces this figure:

[image]

Which plotly version are you running?

Comment: why does the vline does not extend indefinetely on the y axis?

Comment: I am running into this issue as well with plotly 4.12 and would like the vline to extend indefinitely

Comment: Same problem described here https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/2979 but no solution is provided

Comment: thanks for the quick answer but the workaround is quite verbose and not so neat. I am a bit puzzled as doc https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Figure.html?highlight=add_vline#plotly.graph_objects.Figure.add_vline clearly says "Add a vertical line to a plot or subplot that extends infinitely in the y-dimension."

Comment: All examples here https://plotly.com/python/horizontal-vertical-shapes/#horizontal-and-vertical-lines-and-rectangles extends beyond 1 too

Comment: However what you are showing here is exactly what I am facing and what is not the intended behaviour IMO

Comment: Plotly 5.6.0 and this still is bugged